MPAndroidChart change position of stacked column value labels in Stacked Bar Chart
I'm getting this result with the stacked barchart in MPAndroidChart:

However I'd like the individual values for each inner column to be located at the center of their respective column, like this:

I've read the documentation and searched through google and there doesn't seem to be any mention on how to do that. Anyone got any ideas on how to achieve that?
